# Can I change which day I get the Activity.app weekly summary?

Tags: activity.app, apple-watch.app

I always get it on Monday but I would like to get it on Sunday.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like it probably isn't possible. In Apple Watch.app -> My Watch -> Activity there is a toggle that says:

> When this is on, every Monday you'll get a brief recap of your Move
>   performance from the previous week, and you can adjust your Move goal
>   for the upcoming week

Which to me suggests there isn't a setting for changing the day you receive the recap.